# Output Shape not correct

Tags: python, image, scipy, python-imaging-library, glob

One week ago I run this code perfectly. But today I am getting runtime error: output shape not correct

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_list_Brownspot = []

for filename in glob.glob('./dataset/BrownSpot/*.jpg'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list_Brownspot.append(im.copy())
    im.close()

len(image_list_Brownspot)
lap = scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace(image_list_Brownspot[0])
```

`

Comment: Is your folder structure still the same? Are the images where you think they should be and is your code finding them? The cryptic error is sometimes because it failed to find a file so there is nothing where there should be something.

Comment: @Pam yes. the folder structure is still the same